# (Non-limit) distribution of maxima from different univariate, discrete and stationary time series

Tags: time-series, distributions, extreme-value

**Motivation**: I'm currently studying the convergence of maxima from simulated time series to max-stable distributions, and in order to do so, I want to better understand the penultimate distribution of such maxima in non-limit cases. I tried to read Leadbetter et al. (1983) "Extremes and related properties of random sequences and processes", but did not get too far.

**Starting point**: I understand that maxima $M_n$ from a sequence of n iid r.v. $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are distributed according to $P(M_n\leq x)=P(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x,...,X_n\leq x))=F^n(x)$. Thus I manage to derive the penultimate distribution of maxima from a white-noise process with Gaussian innovations.

**Question 0 (New)**: Is $F^n(x)$ even the *penultimate distribution* of the Gaussian, or is this a first misunderstanding? According to [Cohen (1982)](https://doi.org/10.2307/1426524), the penultimate distribution of maxima from a sequence of Gaussians is the Type III Extreme Value distribution / GEV with shape parameter $\xi<0$.

**Question 1**: Is there are closed-form distribution of maxima from an ARMA(2,2) process with Gaussian innovations? I found something on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7150) on maxima of ARMA(1,1) processes. But if there is not such distribution, ...

**Question 2**: ... what is the unconditional (i.e. $P(X_i<x)$, not $P(X_i<x | x_{i-1})$) distribution of ARMA(2,2)-generated r.v., such that one could employ $F^n(x)$ (either ignoring that fact that these r.v. are not independent, or adjusting $n$ such that it accounts for the dependence, e.g. such that $n^*=n/k$, where $k$ is the lag where the ACF/PACF are close enough to zero).

I'm thankful for both every hint you can give me, but also for pointing out if my questions are nonsense.

Comment: One immediate point worth making would be to amend your question to read "distribution(s) of maxima." That said and as Yves points out in his answer, Embrechts, et al., provide the single best introduction and overview wrt *Modeling Extremal Events*. The workhorse distribution for EVT models is the GPD (generalized Pareto distribution) but many other distributional assumptions are possible. The choice is as much a function of field, specialization and training as anything since it can be demonstrated that many distributions will *fit* the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 2**. You want the stationary distribution of the
Gaussian AR process $X_t$
$$
    (1 - \phi_1 B - \dots - \phi_p B^p) \, X_t
    = (1 + \theta_1 B + \dots + \theta_q B^q) \,\varepsilon_t
  $$
for the special case $p=q=2$.  This distribution a.k.a. the
*invariant distribution* is a Gaussian distribution: its mean
$\mu_X$ and sd $\sigma_X$ can be found. In the case where
$\varepsilon_t$ has mean zero we have $\mu_X = 0$ and $$ \sigma_X^2
  = \sigma_\zeta^2 \sum_{k \geq 0} \psi_k^2 $$ where the coefficients $\psi_k$
are the "psi weights" of the $\text{MA}(\infty)$ representation $X_t
  = \sum_{k \geq 0} \psi_k \zeta_{t-k}$ where $\zeta_t$ is a Gaussian
white noise. The "psi weights" are computed by many R packages.
An alternative derivation uses the ARMA model in state-space form:
the state equation defines a vector AR(1) process with $r:= \max\{p,
  \, q + 1\}$. We can assume that the observed series is the first
component of the state $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t$ in the model
\begin{align*}
     \boldsymbol{\alpha}_t &= \mathbf{T} \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{t-1} +
     \boldsymbol{\eta}_t\\
     X_t &= \alpha_{1,t}
  \end{align*}
where both the $r \times r$ transition matrix $\mathbf{T}$ and the
covariance of the Gaussian white noise $\boldsymbol{\eta}_t$ depend
on the ARMA coefficients $\phi_i$, $\theta_j$. The stationary
covariance of the state $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_t$ can be computed by
solving a linear system. See e.g. Chap. 4 of [Harvey A.C. *Time Series
Models*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/time-series-models-second-edition).
For the special case $p = q= 2$ you can find a closed form
for the variance if needed.

**Question 0**. No, $F_X^n(x)$ is not the cited penultimate
distribution, which is a a Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) with
negative shape $\xi_n < 0$ *depending on $n$*.  The penultimate
approximation depending on $n$ improves the convergence rate
compared to the ultimate distribution (here Gumbel). See p. 151 in
[Embrechts P., Klüppelberg C. and Mikosch
T.](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540609315) for a
discussion. In the article by Cohen (1982) cited in OP, a
penultimate approximation is found for a sequence of i.i.d.  normal
and is shown to be such that an approximation with rate $O\{(\log
  n)^{-2}\}$ results instead of the $O\{(\log n)^{-1}\}$ rate known to
hold for the Gumbel approximation.  In Theorem 3, the case of a
Gaussian stationary times series $X_t$ is considered; It is shown
that under mild conditions on the autocorrelation sequence, the
distribution of the maximum differs from that of the maximum $n$ i.i.d. rv.s with
the same margin by $O\{(\log n)^{-2}\}$. So by triangle inequality
the penultimate approximation still leads to the better rate of
convergence when applied to the maximum of stationary Gaussian
sequences.

**Question 1**. I doubt that a closed-form expression would be of a
great practical interest. I think that a good approximation can be
obtained as
$$
  F_{M_n}(x)\approx  F_X^{n\theta} (x)
  $$
where $\theta \in (0,\,1)$ depends on $n$ and on the ARMA
coefficients. For a given size $n$ and given parameters we can find
a $\theta$ that leads to a good approximation for $x$ large enough,
say for $x > 0.95$. Indeed the Gaussian $\text{ARMA}(p,\,q)$ process
with given coefficients is easy to simulate from and thus it is easy
to simulate a sample of maxima $M_n$ and then find a good value for
$\theta$ by censoring the small values of $M_n$.

Comment: Thanks Yves for the extensive explanation! One follow up question, the $\theta$ in your answer to **Question 1** is the extremal index right?

Comment: No, because the extremal index is an "ultimale" concept related to $n \to \infty$ while it is here used in a "penultimate" framework with a given $n$, so at least the estimated value depends on $n$. My findings are that this works fine even for a moderate value of $n$. I have no proof nor any explanation. Sorry for the possibe confusion with MA coefficients, but indeed this idea comes from the extremal index.

Comment: The natural idea you are aware of is that the maximum of $n$ dependent rv.s should be close to that of a smaller number of independent rv.s with the same margin that could be found by declustering.